# PHP ssh2_scp_send remote file name enclosed in single quotes

Tags: php, scp

I'm writing a code to SCP a file from Solaris 10 machine to a router (couldn't be simpler). 
 Here is the code:

```
<?php
$src = "test.txt";
$trg = "test.txt";

echo "Connecting...\n";
$connection = ssh2_connect('myrouter',22);

echo "Authenticating...\n";
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'mylogin', 'mypassword');

echo "Sending...\n";
ssh2_scp_send($connection, $src, $trg);
?>
```

This works just fine but the remote filename is screwed up:

```
10/11/2012  10:57p                  15 'test.txt'
```

Note the single quotes around the file name `test.txt`.

When I use Solaris SCP everything works fine. Here is the command:

```
solaris10$ scp test.txt mylogin@myrouter:test.txt
```

The remote file name looks like:

```
10/11/2012  11:10p                  15 test.txt
```

So the problem seems to be limited to PHP.

Did anybody have similar issue? Where should I start looking?

The remote filesystem is FAT32.

Thank You,
PN.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using ssh2_scp_send().  However, I switched to using ssh2_sftp() and fwrite() and the problem went away.  See examples in the comments on the http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php page.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom comment on this page http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php refers to a problem you might be having;

Can you set `$trg` to the full remote server path?

```
$trg = "/var/www/test.txt";
```

or

```
$trg = "/test.txt";
```

Comment: I saw that page. I assume you refer to the bottom comment there. These examples have syntax errors: 

`- Works: ssh2_scp_send($conn, '/var/tmp/file_01.txt', /var/tmp/file_02.txt');`

will result in a parse error because of missing `'` in the remote file name.

And since the router OS is not UNIX (too bad, should have bought Juniper :) UNIX absolute paths don't work.

Comment: Yes I saw the syntax error too, but thought it might still be relevant anyway. Good luck!